# Flutter parent child checkboxes

Tags: flutter, checkbox, mobile

Is there a built in way to manage parent-child checkboxes for mobile? I was looking at https://material.io/components/selection-controls#checkboxes and it talks about checkboxes having a parent-child relationship. I was expecting something like `children` as a property.

I know I can manage this myself but was wondering if flutter had a built in way of doing it since it was displayed.

Comment: In flutter, you could simply just change the checkbox's value programatically. There is no parent child relationship kind in flutter that would do that but it is possible through setState() and changing the checkbox's value.

Comment: Recently, I wanted the same and I couldn't find any help, so I developed it on my own and it works just like in the material design spec. Here is the article of the same, that I've written on Medium https://medium.com/@nishsvn.dev/flutter-parent-and-child-checkboxes-part-1-5ed0e06cb494. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can use: **Parent Child Checkbox**
Link: https://pub.dev/packages/parent_child_checkbox

Look at:

[image]

1. Import:

> ```
> import 'package:parent_child_checkbox/parent_child_checkbox.dart';
> import 'dart:developer'; // to print Log, show items that checked
> ```

2. Add Parent and Children:

> ```
> Column(
>           children: [
>             ParentChildCheckbox(
>               parent: Text('Parent 1'),
>               children: [
>                 Text('Children 1.1'),
>                 Text('Children 1.2'),
>                 Text('Children 1.3'),
>                 Text('Children 1.4'),
>               ],
>               parentCheckboxColor: Colors.orange,
>               childrenCheckboxColor: Colors.red,
>             ),
>             ParentChildCheckbox(
>               parent: Text('Parent 2'),
>               children: [
>                 Text('Children 2.1'),
>                 Text('Children 2.2'),
>                 Text('Children 2.3'),
>                 Text('Children 2.4'),
>               ],
>             ),
>             ElevatedButton(
>               child: Text('Get Data'),
>               onPressed: () {
>                 log(ParentChildCheckbox.isParentSelected.toString()); 
>                 log(ParentChildCheckbox.selectedChildrens.toString());
>               },
>             ),
>           ],
>         ),
> ```

I hope this helps you bro...